# v-date-picker allow write date with keyboard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vuetify.js

I´m trying to do that my v-date-picker allow that my users can write date with keyboard and select date with date-picker. I´m reading documentation, i´m showing examples... but i can´t find solution. I think that should be very simple but i don´t know how i can to do this. I hope that anybody can help me.

I have this component, `FormDatePicker.vue` that all content it´s:

```
<template>
    <v-flex>
        <strong>{{ label }}</strong>
        <v-menu
            ref="dateMenu"
            v-model="dateMenu"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            :nudge-right="40"
            transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y
            max-width="290px"
            min-width="290px"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-text-field
                    slot="activator"
                    v-model="valorDateFormatted"
                    persistent-hint
                    append-outer-icon="event"
                    clearable
                    solo
                    v-on="on"
                    :error-messages="errorMessages"
                    @click:clear="limpiarDate()"
                ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker
                locale="es-ES"
                v-on="$listeners"
                v-model="currentValue"
                no-title
                first-day-of-week=1
                @input="dateChanged()"
                :min="min"
                :max="max"
                :disabled="desactivar"
                @change="useSelectedData"
            ></v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        inheritAttrs: false,
        data: () => ({
            dateMenu: false,
        }),
        props: {
            errorMessages:  { type: Array, default: null},
            label:          { type: String, default: ''},
            value:          { default: ''},                     //Nota: Elimino el type: String porque provoca un error cuando le paso números.
            min: { type: String, default: null },
            max: { type: String, default: null },
            desactivar: { type: Boolean, default: null}
        },
        computed: {
            inputListeners: function () {
                var vm = this
                // `Object.assign` merges objects together to form a new object
                return Object.assign({},
                    // We add all the listeners from the parent
                    this.$listeners,
                    // Then we can add custom listeners or override the
                    // behavior of some listeners.
                    {
                        // This ensures that the component works with v-model
                        input: function (event) {
                            vm.$emit('input', event.target.value)
                        }
                    }
                )
            },
            valorDateFormatted: {
                get : function () {
                    return this.formatDate(this.value);
                },
                set: function(value) {
                    return this.formatDate(value);
                }
            },
            currentValue: {
                get: function() {
                    if (this.value != null) {
                        return this.value.split(' ')[0];
                    }
                    return this.value;
                },
                set: function(val) {
                    this.$emit('input', val);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            dateChanged() {
                this.dateMenu = false;
            },
            formatDate (date) {
                if (!date) return null

                const [year, month, day] = date.split(' ')[0].split('-')
                return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
            },

            limpiarDate(){
                this.$emit('input', null);
            },
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .theme--light.v-input >>> input, .theme--light.v-input >>> textarea{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

I tryed add @blur and function tu blur, i tryed add @focus and function to focus, but not run.

Thank your very much for read me and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read Shkirkov's answer and I think it can be done simpler.

What we want is to bind 2 values in the v-text-field v-model: the date value by the date picker and the one written with the keyboard. For that, we have to define the getter and setter in the computed variable and we CAN NOT put "readonly" as an attribute for v-date-picker.

Your template will look like this:

```
<template>
  <v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="290px"
  >
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formattedDate"
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
        ref="datePicker"
      />
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      color="secondary"
      locale="ru-RU"
      no-title
      v-model="internalDate"
      @input="onDatePickerValueChanged"
      :first-day-of-week="1"
      :max="max"
    />
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

And as for your script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'x-date-picker',
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
      internalDate: null¿
    }
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * v-date-picker uses format YYYY-MM-DD, but out local format is DD.MM.YYYY
     */
    formattedDate: {
      get() {
        return (this.internalDateValue && this.internalDateValue.length === 10)
          ? this.$moment(this.internalDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
          : this.internalDateValue
      },
      set(newValue) {
         if(newValue && newValue.length==10){
             let newDate = `${newValue.substring(6, 10)}-${newValue.substring(3, 5)}-${newValue.substring(0, 2)}`
             this.internalDate = newDate
      }
    }
```

We need to pass to internalDate the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD because is the date picker's format!

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

To allow users to input dates using the keyboard and select dates using the `date-picker`, you can make use of the `editable` & the `readonly` prop of the `v-date-picker` component in Vuetify. Then use the @input to capture the keyboard input & the @change event to capture the datapicker data.

Example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" lazy offset>
      <v-date-picker v-model="date" :editable="editable" :readonly="false" @input="updateSelectedDate" @change="useSelectedData"></v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: i updated my question with your code example, but i can write date, only i can select

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to build such a component, but unfortunately there's no good examples in documentation.

`v-date-picker` internally works with `YYYY-MM-DD`-strings only, so the main problem is to convert these strings into your local country format. I can provide an example of date-picker with `DD.MM.YYYY` input format, and you can change this format to your local.

It is not a fully production-ready component, but I guess this can be a good starting point for you. In this example I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library to convert dates format, but you can use another library (Luxon?) or write your own convertor:

```js
<template>
  <v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="290px"
  >
    <template #activator="{ on: onMenu }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formattedDate"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        v-on="{ ...onMenu, ...$listeners }"
        ref="datePicker"
      />
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      color="secondary"
      locale="ru-RU"
      no-title
      v-model="internalDate"
      @input="onDatePickerValueChanged"
      :first-day-of-week="1"
      :max="max"
    />
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'x-date-picker',
  props: {
    value: String,
    max: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
      internalDate: this.value,
      internalDateValue: this.value
    }
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * v-date-picker uses format YYYY-MM-DD, but out local format is DD.MM.YYYY
     */
    formattedDate: {
      get() {
        return (this.internalDateValue && this.internalDateValue.length === 10)
          ? this.$moment(this.internalDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
          : this.internalDateValue
      },
      set(newValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue.length < 11) {
          if (newValue.length === 2 || newValue.length === 5) {
            this.internalDateValue = newValue + "."
            this.internalDate = null
          } else if (newValue.length === 10) {
            let newDate = `${newValue.substring(6, 10)}-${newValue.substring(3, 5)}-${newValue.substring(0, 2)}`
            let newDateObject = new Date(newDate)
            if (this.isValidDate(newDateObject)) {
              if (this.max !== null && (new Date(this.max).getTime() < newDateObject.getTime())) {
                this.internalDate = this.max
                this.internalDateValue = this.max
              } else {
                this.internalDate = newDate
                this.internalDateValue = newDate
              }
            } else {
              this.internalDate = null
              this.internalDateValue = null
              this.$refs.datePicker.internalValue = null
            }
            this.$emit('update', this.internalDate)
          } else {
            this.internalDateValue = newValue
            this.internalDate = null
          }
        } else {
          this.internalDate = null
          this.internalDateValue = null
          this.$emit('update', this.internalDate)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.internalDate = val
      this.internalDateValue = val
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * User input date validation
     */
    isValidDate(val) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === "[object Date]") {
        return !isNaN(val.getTime())
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },

    /**
     * Actions on v-date-picker selection changed
     */
    onDatePickerValueChanged() {
      this.$emit('update', this.internalDate)
      this.menu = false
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Usage:

```js
<x-date-picker
  :value="editedItem.date"
  label="Select date"
  @update="editedItem.date = $event"
  :rules="rules.date"
/>
...
data() {
  return {
    editedItem: {
      date: '2023-03-04',
    },
    rules: {
      date: [
        v => !!v || 'This field is required',
        v => (v && v.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 8) || 'This date is incorrect'
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

There's a [CodeSandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-71092015-forked-nzygzc).

Comment: i really don't know how this work. What doest it mean 'v-on="{ ...onMenu, ...$listeners }"'?

Comment: @ladytoky0, you need to mix event listeners from wrapper component (x-date-picker) and vuetify's v-menu component, and then put them all into v-text-field component, because you need to respond to user input changes. You might also find [Vue2 $listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) links helpful